# Where can I find some "humanized" C# tutorials?

Tags: c#

I've decided to start learning C#, but all the tutorials I can find are very dry and speak to the reader as if the reader is a machine.

How about some tutorials that talk to me like I'm a human?

Comment: You should have listed some of those tutorials. Now you'll get them all back again.

Comment: @BoltClock To make me kill humans, insert coin :-P

Comment: If you want to program a *machine*, you'd better think like a *machine*;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is about as friendly an introduction as I could find](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html)

Comment: Your link is currently giving me a 404.

Comment: @Oren, @Flo, @Rob - It had an extra `.` on the end, fixed it.

Comment: Taking a look at it right now. Looks promising

Answer (score 2):

I'd also have a look over *Head First C#* if I were you

Answer (score 1):

When I went to a training course by Microsoft to learn C#, I received a complimentary copy of [Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition: Build a Program Now!](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12281&locale=en-us) by Microsoft Press, and actually found it a pretty pleasant read.

I agree with the rest that you're more likely to find 'humanized' tutorials in books than online. I've read so many tutorials myself and know what you mean when you say they're dry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the books of [wrox](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Visual-C-Revised-Edition-of-Beginning-C-for-NET-v1-0.productCd-0764543822.html) and [O'reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003098). They are very reader friendly, ands very good.

They explaina large scala of c# in a very understandable manner. I believe a book is better then a tutorial, because the concepts are linked together so it is easier to understand.

One of the best books for beginners I know is [head first](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514822)

Answer (score 0):

In that case probably the best tutorial source would be a book. The tutorials you will find online are very generalized and usually intend to teach the reader how to accomplish a specific task. The worst thing about online tutorials is the fact that those are not structured. Therefore, as you go, you can get confused on what to learn next.

I would recommend starting with [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform, Fifth Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) by Andrew Troelsen. It starts with the basics and goes on to more complex elements in a very structured way, so you learn step-by-step. You can also try tackling [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471) by Jon Skeet - it is one of the best books you can currently find on C#.

One more thing - the best way to learn a language in my opinion is not by tutorials but by having small tasks and trying to accomplish them. For example, you want to learn how to write to a text file. You research this topic and eventually you find out more about the whole process and why it works the way it does. The syntax understanding comes with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Book a very good and gentle introduction to C#.
[C# Yellow Book](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/)